# For Loop in a Boolean Function Always Returns False

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble determining what I'm doing wrong in a portion of my code.
I'm trying to make it so that the second part of this loop returns false for when there is a portion of a string like `0w`, `1w`, or `5/`. 
However, it returns false on every string entered into the function that is called. 
The first portion of the loop where I specify that only certain characters are allowed works by itself, but the second portion does not work by itself. 
Also, the first portion doesn't work when combined with the second portion.

I'll guess that whatever I'm doing wrong is a pretty simple fix, but I'm just not sure what it is. 
Also, for clarification, I'm looking to build on the second part of that loop with other if statements (if it looks weird that I didn't just omit the if `(isdigit(motion[i]))` line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

bool isMotionMeaningful(string motion) //function should return true if it doesn't return false before that 
{
    for (int i = 0; i != motion.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (!isdigit(motion[i])) //this portion of the loop works in isolation
        {
            if ((motion[i] != 'W') && (motion[i] != 'w') && (motion[i] != 'S') && (motion[i] != 's') && (motion[i] != 'D') && (motion[i] != 'd') && (motion[i] != 'A') && (motion[i] != 'a') && (motion[i] != '/'))
            {
            return false; 
            }
        if (isdigit(motion[i]))
            {
            if ((motion[i] == '0') || (motion[i] == '1')) //if these digits are followed by a number or a slash
                {
                  int j = i + 1;
                  if (!isdigit(motion[j]) || motion[j] == '/')
                      {
                      return false;
                      }
                }
            }
       }        
   }     
   return true;
}   

int main ()
{
if (isMotionMeaningful("3w///10d//////////"))
    cout << "This case should work\n";
if (!isMotionMeaningful("z3w///10d//////////"))
    cout << "This case shouldn't work because it has a bad character\n";
if (!isMotionMeaningful("0w///10d//////////"))
    cout << "This case shouldn't work because it uses 0 by itself\n";
if (!isMotionMeaningful("2///10d//////////"))
    cout << "This case shouldn't work because it is a number is followed by a slash\n";

return 0; 
}
```

It outputs:

```
This case should work
This case shouldn't work because it has a bad character
```

Comment: Have you traced through in a debugger to see what is happening?  You also might want to edit the code so it actually compiles.

Comment: You occasionally are comparing characters to strings (i.e. `motion[j] == "/"`), and I believe you forgot a `}` to close the first `if` block.

Comment: I really don't understand what kind of compilers people are using to post non-compiling code. I edited the code inside the question.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance. I apologize, I was copying over parts of my code and removing those that were not relevant to the issue at hand. In the process, I had accidentally put in a part that did not compile. However, I'm still getting the issue of the latter two strings in the main function not printing to the command prompt since the two corresponding strings run through the called function should be false based on the second loop.

Comment: If you want to remove irrelevant code, remove it. Then compile and run what remains, and verify that the error still occurs, before you post it.

Comment: It's funny how often the irrelevant code turns out to be the code that's broken.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I answer it.

There is a reason we use indent carefully, not just for aesthetics.
Change the following part:

```
    if (!isdigit(motion[i]))
    {
        // do something
        if (isdigit(motion[i]))
        {
            // your program will never get here
        }
    }
```

to:

```
    if (!isdigit(motion[i]))
    {
        // do something
    } else {
        // ...
    }
```